# Converting Import Wizard to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste data into my excel sheet using text import wizard.

I want to do the following steps in VBA:

- select 'Use Text Import Wizard' from the paste options (after having copied the text data)
- Check 'Delimited' and 'My data has headers' boxes (if not already checked by defaults) then hit next
- From Delimiters section select 'tab', unselect 'space' then set 'Text Qualifiers' as 'none' (make sure the 'Treat consecutive delimiters as one' box is unchecked then hit next.
- In this section just format the 3rd column as 'Text' then hit finish.

I tried doing:

With ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial format:="Unicode Text", Link:False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

This is the code I got from recording, but didn't get me the desired results.

I should note that the text I am copying from is SQL, and when I paste the normal way there are a few hundred records missing. Hence why I use the Text Import Wizard and apply the settings mentioned above. This ensures all records are pasted from sql.